# Connecting an app to a SQL Server database

Tags: android, sql-server

I want to connect my app to a SQL Server database

I created this loginActivity:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;



public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    // Declaring layout button, edit texts
    Button login;
    EditText username,password;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    // End Declaring layout button, edit texts

    // Declaring connection variables
    Connection con;
    String un,pass,db,ip;
    //End Declaring connection variables

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        // Getting values from button, texts and progress bar
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtStagiaireName);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtStagiairePass);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        // End Getting values from button, texts and progress bar

        // Declaring Server ip, username, database name and password
        ip = "192.168.1.9:1433";
        db = "dbcom";
        un = "sa";
        pass = "123456";
        //End Declaring Server ip, username, database name and password

        // Setting up the function when button login is clicked
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                CheckLogin checkLogin = new CheckLogin();// this is the Asynctask, which is used to process in background to reduce load on app process
                checkLogin.execute("");
            }
        });
        //End Setting up the function when button login is clicked
    }

    public class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        String z = "";
        Boolean isSuccess = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r)
        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(isSuccess)
            {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this , "Login Successfull" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //finish();
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            String usernam = username.getText().toString();
            String passwordd = password.getText().toString();
            if(usernam.trim().equals("")|| passwordd.trim().equals(""))
                z = "Please enter Username and Password";
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    con = connectionclass(un, pass, db, ip);        // Connect to database
                    if (con == null)
                    {
                        z = "Check Your Internet Access!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Change below query according to your own database.
                        String query = "select * from Stagiaire where username= '" + usernam.toString() + "' and password = '"+ passwordd.toString() +"'  ";
                        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                        if(rs.next())
                        {
                            z = "Login successful";
                            isSuccess=true;
                            con.close();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            z = "Invalid Credentials!";
                            isSuccess = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    isSuccess = false;
                    z = ex.getMessage();
                }
            }
            return z;
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection connectionclass(String user, String password, String database, String server)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection connection = null;
        String ConnectionURL = null;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server +";databaseName="+ database + ";user=" + user+ ";password=" + password + ";";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
        }
        catch (SQLException se)
        {
            Log.e("error here 1 : ", se.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.e("error here 2 : ", e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("error here 3 : ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

when I compile the project and putting the username and password, always I get this Toast: Check Your Internet Access!
That means connectionURL = null.
But why? Please if there is anything wrong in my code, please inform me!

```
12-02 22:43:23.116 2388-2388/com.reddivx.ismo.advancedismo I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
12-02 22:43:23.116 2388-2388/com.reddivx.ismo.advancedismo W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
12-02 22:43:23.300 2388-2388/com.reddivx.ismo.advancedismo W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.reddivx.ismo.advancedismo-2/lib/x86
12-02 22:43:23.314 2388-2388/com.reddivx.ismo.advancedismo I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
12-02 22:43:23.394 2388-2388/com.reddivx.ismo.advancedismo W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
12-02 22:43:24.630 2388-2388/com.reddivx.ismo.advancedismo W/gralloc_ranchu: Gralloc pipe failed

                                                                             [ 12-02 22:43:24.632  2388: 2388 D/         ]
                                                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9ae3d7c0, tid 2388
12-02 22:43:24.674 2388-2409/com.reddivx.ismo.advancedismo I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-02 22:43:24.674 2388-2409/com.reddivx.ismo.advancedismo D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
12-02 22:45:19.093 2388-2388/com.reddivx.ismo.advancedismo W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
12-02 22:46:44.606 2388-2968/com.reddivx.ismo.advancedismo E/error here 1 :: Network error IOException: Connection refused
```

Comment: Can you add the stack trace?

Comment: I meant your logcat logs.

Comment: @lakshman.pasala Done!

Comment: Are you on the same network as the SQL server?

Comment: it's in my Laptop .. I create a database on it, and I wanna access to its data

Comment: Which network is the app connected to?

Comment: I am not even sure if what you are doing is possible on Android, I don't think Android ships with a JDBC driver, try [this](https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid) maybe?

Comment: @lakshman.pasala Wifi

Comment: @MahmoudElmorabea yeah  it's possible ..  and I have seen a lot of people doing it

Comment: @Dev I understand that Android has the interfaces for that, but I don't think it has the driver implementation, I posted an answer with a post and library to help you do that

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use JDBC on Android out of the box.
Please refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105529/how-to-connect-android-with-mysql-using-mysql-jdbc-driver)

Also check [this library](https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid) if you want to use JDBC on ANdroid

Comment: if you don't mind, please leave comment having my code after the editing that I should do